# How to add to my search link ?search="word"?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to add to my route from search page something like `topic/category?search="word"`, but I don't know how to add it.

Now, in my view I get the word above  my content :

```
 @if(isset($details))
        <p> The Search results for your query <b> {{ $query }} </b> are :</p>
@endif
<form action="/topic/{{strtolower($category->category)}}/career-solutions" method="POST" role="search">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <input type="hidden" name="c" value="{{$category->id }}">
     <input type="hidden" name="d" value="{{$category->category }}">
     <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q"
             placeholder="Search content"> <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
             </button>
         </span>
     </div>
 </form>
```

Here is my route and what I tried:

```
Route::any ( '/topic/{category?}/career-solutions/{q?}/{page?}', 'CategoryController@searchCareer' );
```

Here is my controller:

```
$q = Input::get ( 'q' );
$user = CareerSolution::where ( 'subject', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )
                      ->where('career_solutions.topic_category_id', '=', $c)
        ->join('role_users' , 'role_users.user_id', '=', 'career_solutions.user_id')
        ->join('roles' , 'roles.id', '=', 'role_users.role_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'career_solutions.user_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'career_solutions.topic_category_id')
        ->orWhere ( 'career_solutions.user_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )
        ->orWhere ( 'career_solutions.id', '=', 'events.subject')
        ->orWhere('career_solutions.topic_category_id' ,'=', $category->id)
        ->orWhere ( 'career_solutions.user_id', '=', 'users.username')
       ->select('career_solutions.id as id','subject','users.id as user_id','username', 'profile_picture', 'role_id', 'optional', 'topic_category_id','categories.category')
        ->get();





        if (count ( $user ) > 0)
                return view ( 'category-search',$data )->withDetails ( $user )->withQuery ( $q )->with(compact('topic_id'))->with(compact('account'))->with(compact('category'))->with(compact('c'))->with(compact('d'));
        else
                return view ( 'category-search',$data )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
```

Now, when I press search, it opens a page with link `/topic/courses/career-solutions`, I need to add to it ...`?sesrch="word"` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using query paramter, the http verb should be GET,

Next the url will be something like

```
/?x=y&p=q
```

so the form action will be

```
<form action="/topic/{{strtolower($category->category)}}/career-solutions?x=y&p=q" method="GET" role="search">
```

and in your controller

```
$x = $request->input('x');
```

and

```
$p = $request->input('q');
```

Comment: Hm, seems is working, but can I remove `_token` from my link ?

Comment: @Andrew if you are using `$request->all()` or some form request class, just unset token in controller like `$records = $request->all();` and `unset($records['_token'])`

Comment: Hm, the link is changed, but I'm not redirected to the page with results for my search :(

Comment: @Andrew Are you able to get the query parameters in your controller?

Comment: Yes, I am . Maybe is a problem with my route ? `Route::get('/topic/{category?}/career-solutions/{page?}', 'CategoryController@searchCareer' );`

Comment: @Andrew Have you written this, in your controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201380/discussion-between-andrew-and-prafulla-kumar-sahu).

Comment: If you won't the `_token` you could make like this: `$request->except(['_token']);`

Comment: Now, I'm not redirected to `return view ( 'category-search',$data )`, my page just reloading and the link is changed with `&p= ...`

Comment: @Andrew Can you post your code in gist and share the link with me?

Comment: I will post it tomorrow, now my job just ended :) Cya tomorrow mate !

Comment: @Andrew okay, I am also going to leave office in 10/15 minutes.catch you tomorrow.